# AngularJS : one ng-click call the function twice why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have following angularjs code. When I click li tag that function is invoke twice. That means on click two request is passing and i'm getting two response why? Even i change ng-click to only radio button that function invoke only once why?

```
 <li ng-click="togglePrice(2);">
  <input type="radio" name="personalGroup" ng-model="watchlist" value="watchlist" id="watchlist">
  <label for="watchlist" >My Watchlist</label>
</li>
```

script

```
  $scope.togglePrice = function (price) {
        console.log(price+"newwww"); 
        .................
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have interaction events attached to non-interactive elements, that's just bad practice.

Comment: Can u please elaborate or explain with example bez I'm new in Angularjs

Comment: That has nothing todo with AngularJS, its HTML practice. Non-interactive elements like `<li>`, `<div>`, `<span>`, etc. should not have events attached to them (clicks, for example). These should be used only in interactive elements like `<a>`, `<button>`, so on.

Comment: A click event on the `<label>` element creates a click event on the `<input>` element. The `ng-click` directive on the `<li>` receives both click events. Use `event.target.tagName` to differentiate between the two events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get this behaviour because of `<input type="radio">` inside your `<li>`

You can write `<li ng-click="togglePrice(2);$event.preventDefault()">` to get rid of second click. However your radio button state will not change.

<kbd>[DEMO plunkr 1](https://plnkr.co/edit/wW7SZVO4GqiFBFMNmWjX?p=preview)</kbd>

---

Maybe you wanted something like:

*Controller*

```
$scope.watchlist = 'City1';    
$scope.list = ["City1", "City2","City3"];
```

*HTML*

```
<li  ng-repeat="watchlist in list">
 <label>
       <input type="radio" name="personalGroup" 
       ng-model="$parent.watchlist" 
       ng-value="watchlist"
       ng-change="togglePrice(watchlist)" />{{watchlist}}
      </label>
</li>
```

<kbd>[DEMO plunkr 2](https://plnkr.co/edit/wiyrAtn2WxOMUyQVOmlf?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Bro i want to check the radio button when click.. so only i did like this. Any other way solve this issue. Even i use 'a' tag i cant check the radio button.

Comment: @Rijo if you want to check radio button, and catch its state you don't need `ng-click` directive